# Need help matching a string if it ONLY contains approved substrings

Tags: pattern-matching, validation

I am having a hard time writing this regular expression.

Basically I need to block email delivery if the message recipient envelope contains an unapproved domain.  My internet mail gateway (Brightmail) allows to create rules where I can specify a condition using Match/DoesNotMatch a regular expression.

For example I need only allow mail to yahoo.com, hotmail.com, and gmail.com.

If someone sends a message to some other domain, the message should be blocked.

If someone sends a message to yahoo.com AND some other domain, the message should be blocked

If someone sends a message to yahoo.com, the message should be allowed.

Is this possible?

If someone sends a message to yahoo.com and hotmail.com, the message should be allowed.

I am not a total noob with regular expression, but this one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like its possible.  It would be a token find where you have a series of OR operators between tokens.

I don't know if you have ever used this site, but it is a GODSEND when I am developing regex queries.

http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Thanks. I am playing with Regexpal now.

Comment: I think I got something...  not a match on a domain name, but a match on something@ before the domain name  :)    - regex is (?!(.*@yahoo\.com|.*@hotmail\.com|.*@gmail\.com)).*@

Comment: I think this is what you want: .*(\@hotmail\.com)|.*(\@yahoo\.com)|.*(\@gmail\.com)

Comment: The above regex I made with regexpal and it will return a match on any email address that matches the three domains listed above.  If you want to find invalid email addresses then it is the inverse of finding a match, it is finding email addresses that DONT match.

Comment: Mathing what's listed is easy. Matching what is not listed is not as easy as it seems. A simple inverse will not cut it.

Answer (score 0):

I played with RegexPal and picked a combination that will satisfy my needs.

Basically this will match the substrings before the @ character for only those strings that ARE NOT the listed ones.

> (?!(.*@yahoo.com|.*@hotmail.com|.*@gmail.com)).*@

or even this will work

> (?!(.*@yahoo.com|.*@hotmail.com|.*@gmail.com))@

or this

> @(?!(.*@yahoo.com|.*@hotmail.com|.*@gmail.com))

or even better

> @(?!(.*(yahoo|hotmail|gmail).com))

The last one will just highlight the @ sign in the domain name strings that do Not belong.

Comment: weird... I put the backslashes before .coms in my post... but this website filtered them out